# run a script in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to run a script in production.  This script generates a record and inserts it into the production db.  My problem is that the script tries to insert the record into the development db.

run_report.rb

```
 ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'production'
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'daemons'

 Daemons.run('report.rb')
```

report.rb

```
 ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'production'
 ...
  @r = Report.new(:info => @info)
  @r.save
```

I've tried:
script/rails runner run_report.rb start

script/rails runner run_report.rb start production

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails r script/foo.rb
```

Comment: Important note: The script path is relative to the root of your project, not working dir.  (That little bit stuck me for too long.)