# How to run clockwork script in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, production-environment, clockwork

I am using clockwork gem. I want to automatically delete all comments from `comments` table every day at midnight.

This `app/clock.rb` script is working as it supposed to in development env.:

```
require './config/boot'
require './config/environment'
require 'clockwork'

module Clockwork
  every(1.day, 'delete.comment', at: '00:00') {
    Comment.destroy_all
  }
end
```

when it's running on my local terminal with `$ clockwork app/clock.rb`.

So I deployed the app to Heroku. Later in a terminal, I run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails r app/clock.rb
```

[as in this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073066/run-a-script-in-production) but only output is:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 13973
```

and it quits to prompt and comments are still there (assuming the value in `at:` hash has passed).

This is my first individual project.
My question is how to make this script running nonstop in production to remove comments automatically every day at midnight?
OR
more general:
how to run script nonstop in production.

I read [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37453516/how-start-clockwork-in-production-environment) but the answers are not very thorough and first link above is neither, as for a beginner to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create rake task and call form clock.rb

```
every(1.day, 'name', at: '09:00')  do
    #Load task
    Rake::Task['comment:destroy'].invoke
end
```

rake task:

## lib/tasks/comment.rake

```
namespace :comment do
  desc 'Destroy all comment'
  task destroy: :environment do
    Comment.destroy_all
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for response. When `every` method is not enclosed within `module Clockwork` I get  `NoMethodError`, when enclosed, I get `uninitialized constant Clockwork::Rake` while running `clockwork app/clock.rb`. I `require` all three as above. Doing as you suggest and in dev.env(without running `clockwork` in terminal) - nothing is happening. Doing a rake task(I have it in `rake -T`) I still need to run `clockwork` from a terminal in dev.env. In dev. my code is working. Problem is, how to make it running in production. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for effort. After all, I managed this by rake task and without `clockwork` gem.
I created a rake task, deploy it to heroku, and ran task through [heroku scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) addon. Now it's running as a background job.